# Why does Clipboard.GetText() need the Clipboard to be clearable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[The documentation for Clipboard.GetText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.gettext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Clipboard_GetText) states that it can raise an `ExternalException` if:

> The Clipboard could not be cleared.

Why would `GetText` need the Clipboard to be clearable?

Comment: "This typically occurs when the Clipboard is being used by another process."

Comment: Have you thought about looking at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Clipboard.cs,4f77555bdf0239c8) for an answer? I don't know if it will help or not, but worth a shot.

Comment: @mason Thanks. I don't see anything there that would explain it. What am I missing?

Comment: i'm guessing the documentation is bad. look `https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Clipboard.cs,240`

Comment: @DanielA.White If that would be brought as a reason the clipboard is not _readable_ that would make sense. But _clearable_?

Comment: I would recommend submitting feedback on that documentation, or even diving right into the docs and contributing directly and submitting a pull request to fix the docs (https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/blob/master/xml/System.Windows.Forms/Clipboard.xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this seems like an oddity in the documentation. After tracing through [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Clipboard.cs,4f77555bdf0239c8), I can't think of a reason it needs to be clearable as it doesn't appear to attempt to try clearing it.

The second part ("This typically occurs when the Clipboard is being used by another process.") does appear accurate though.
Seems to me the part about text being clearable could have been copied from [Clipboard.SetText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [Clipboard.Clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2), as they are word-for-word the same, but seems far more applicable (although I did not go deeply into the source on this one).

Comment: This sounds right. Or maybe from [Clipboard.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @ispiro - That is true. SetText just came to mind because I've used it more than Clear, but they do call largely the same code internally so I can add that bit to my answer.